# hosting an angular 2 app in an application under localhost

Tags: angular, iis

I'm a beginner an angular2 and started working on a project based on examples I found. When hosting my app on windows it accessible at http:/localhost (or with npm http://localhost:3000) but if I try put it on IIS under localhost/MyApp is still tries to navigate under localhost.

you can find sample code I used at:
https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM%20-%20Final

is there any easy way of doing this?[image]

Comment: have you set default page?

Comment: Yes. still happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: in your index.html of angular 2 app, edit `<base href="/MyApp/">`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. I also had to change that path to npm at system.js config.

Comment: One more thing though. Now that I use the MyApp at in code. npm start looks for localhost:3000/Myapp witch is not correct. I can see my code run on IIS but could I still run it on node?

Comment: Don't know the answer for your follow up question. Maybe you can develop your angular 2 app with angular cli, and before serving under IIS, you just run `ng build --base-href /myUrl/`. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml